# Layout Controller in yield of Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to put my layout of UsersController inside the yield of ApplicationController
so if I am in an UsersController action then i will get:

```
# application.html.rb layout
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<%= ::I18n.locale %>">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>

# users.html.rb layout

<p>i am in the users layout</p>
<%= yield %>

# index.html.erb (action index of users controller)
<p> i am in the users index action</p>
```

Final:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<%= ::I18n.locale %>">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>i am in the users layout</p>
    <p> i am in the users index action</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No no, I want to use both, application controller AND users layout. Look my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this using `content_for`.

In `application.html.erb` we write

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<%= ::I18n.locale %>">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield(:nested_layout) if content_for?(:nested_layout) %> 
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then in your `index.html.erb` you can write

```
<% content_for :nested_layout do %>
  <p>i am in the users layout</p>  
<% end %>
<p> i am in the users index action</p>
```

In this trivial example it looks like overkill, but `content_for` is really powerful, and can be use to add extra information to header, footer, ...

While this would solve your example, the example is of course very simple and it might not suffice for your specific case. On the rails guide they have an example using nested layouts, which extends on this idea: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts